# Unable to link IOKit driver against IOHIDFamily: "dependency load failed"

Tags: c++, macos, kernel, driver, iokit

I'm developing a macOS IOKit kernel driver extending from IOHIDFamily, but xcode is giving me linking errors such as:

```
Allocating an object of abstract class type 'IOHIDDevice'
```

and kextload gives me the error:

```
(libkern/kext) dependency load failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
```

How can I properly link against IOHIDFamily to fix these errors so I can create classes inheriting from IOHIDFamily classes such as IOHIDDevice?

I have already added this to my Info.plist:

```xml
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily</key>
        <string>2.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>17.7</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>17.7</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>17.7</string>
    </dict>
```

These are the system/kernel logs from kextload:

```
Resetting IOCatalogue.
MacOS error: -67062
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7f99b7bf47c0 [0x7fff83ef4af0]> { URL = "file:///tmp/IOHIDTest.kext/", ID = "org.muirey03.driver.IOHIDTest" }
/tmp/IOHIDTest.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies.
org.muirey03.driver.IOHIDTest's dependencies failed security checks; failing.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jvarela This doesn't look like a signing issue. `Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed:` indicates that SIP is disabled and unsigned kexts are permitted.

Comment: @TommyMuir As the output from `kextload` suggests, can you please retry loading the kext using `kextutil`? This provides error messages which are more specific.

Comment: @TommyMuir "Allocating an object of abstract class type 'IOHIDDevice'" is ringing some alarm bells for me - are you implementing all of the superclasses' pure virtual methods, such as `newReportDescriptor()`? I assume you're not trying to directly create an instance of `IOHIDDevice` itself? If there are errors you don't understand, please post the exact error and the line causing the error and any relevant context.

Comment: @TommyMuir In addition to the output of `kextutil`, the output from `kextlibs -undef-symbols -multdef-symbols -unsupported /tmp/IOHIDTest.kext` may also prove useful, so please add that to your question as well.

Comment: @pmdj You are correct. I wan't implementing `newReportDescriptor` which was the issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue wasn't related to linking at all. I wasn't defining the pure virtual method `newReportDescriptor` on my subclass of IOHIDDevice, which made my subclass into an abstract class which couldn't be allocated.